How can you make an ionic textarea fill it's parent container?
I can't figure out how to make an ion-textarea expand to fill up it's parent!
<ion-textarea
  labelPlacement="floating"
  [placeholder]="placeholder"
  counter="true"
  [maxlength]="maxLength"

>

  <!-- Label-->
  <div class="label" slot="label"> {{ label }}
    @if (true) {
      <ion-text>*</ion-text>
    }
  </div>

</ion-textarea>

And scss code:
:host {
  // display: block; /* Ensure the component respects parent layout */
  // height: 100%;
  display: flex; /* Use flexbox to handle layout */
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Ensure the parent container has a height */
}

/** Main Styles */
.monkey-text-area,
.label-textarea-wrapper,
label,
.ion-textarea-fill {
  flex: 1; /* Allow the textarea to grow and fill the parent */
  --min-height: 100%; /* Set minimum height to fill parent */
  --max-height: 100%; /* Ensure it doesn't exceed parent's height */
  --padding-top: 0;
  --padding-bottom: 0;

  // display: flex;
  // flex: 1;
  // --min-height: 0;
  // --max-height: 100%;


  // height: 100%;
  // width: 100%;
  // --min-height: 100%;
  // --max-height: 100%;

  // ion-textarea {
    // height: 100%;
    // width: 100%;
    // --height: 100%;
    // --width: 100%;
    --background: transparent;
  // }
}

Sorry for the scatter-gun. But nothing makes a blind bit of difference to the height. The only thing that any effect is the rows property. This seems a bit disappointing to me? Unless I'm missing something.

Adding the css attribute of height works. but for that you can use row like it states in the docs, which is the same thing as adding height. and use the other prop called autogrow to scale the area accordingly.

I think your suggestion to use rows is the closest we will get to a 'correct' answer. That or the acknowledgment that this may not be achievable in Ionic in a maintainable way.
